# why the test curve does start from the beginning not from the end of train curve?

Tags: testing, curve

```
# 5-split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.75)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]
print(len(train), len(test))

# Plot train and test data
plt.figure(figsize = (15, 10))
plt.plot(train)
plt.plot(test)
plt.xlabel('Vehicle')
plt.ylabel('Sender Speed')
plt.legend(['Train set', 'Test set'], loc='upper right')

print('Dimension of train data: ',train.shape)
print('Dimension of test data: ', test.shape)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrcFK.png)

why the test curve does start from the beginning not from the end of the train curve?

Answer (score 0):

The source code above breaks the dataset into two groups: the training set and the testing set. The training set is 75% of the data. The testing set is 25%.
The training set and testing set must be kept separate from one another, otherwise you will be training with the test data and the result will likely overfit the data.
It is arbitrary whether the first 25%, the last 25%, or some other 25% of the data is selected for the test set. (In fact the size of the test set is somewhat arbitrary.) In the source above, the test set is selected from the end of the total data set. It should be noted that if the data set is ordered, this may cause a problem. The source code might be improved by randomly reordering the data before selection. The training and testing may be improved by wrangling (cleaning) the data along with sizing and visualizing before training.

Comment: Thank you for the response. my problem is that even though the test set is selected from the end of the total data set when I plot it, the test set doesn't continue from the end of the train set and it shows from the beginning!

Comment: I'm  not sure I understand the question, but there are two plots in the source: one is for test data, the other for training data. In both sets the independent variable, the index of the elements begins at zero. So, there are two plots beginning at the origin. If a plot of the entire data set is required; instead of plotting both the training and testing sets, simply plot the entire data set. Is that the goal?

Comment: The problem is that the test curve begins from zero instead of begins from the end of the train curve!